# DataReader into WPF TextBox vs RichTextBox

Tags: c#, wpf

When I set the TextBox.Text property equal to DataReader.GetString(x), my data displays correctly.

```
while (dr.Read())
{
    string data = dr.GetString(2);
    contentTextBox.Text = data;
}
```

However, I'm trying to use a RichTextBox instead of a TextBox to take advantage of the RichTextBox.Find method, but when I do this it fills the RichTextBox with a new line after each character

```
while (dr.Read())
{
    string data = dr.GetString(2);
    contentRichTextBox.AppendText(data);
}
```

How can I get the string data into the RichTextBox with the correct formatting (ie: the same way that it is read into TextBox.Text)?

Thanks!

Comment: I think the RichTextBox is not wide enough.  Try setting the width property to a larger value.

Comment: @jdweng That was it! Width was set to "Auto" for both the TextBox and RichTextbox, but I guess RichTextBox doesn't automatically resize based on the content. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

@jdweng suggested that the RichTextBox was not wide enough. This was definitely one of the issues since its width was set to "Auto." Even though the regular TextBox automatically resizes based on content if it's Width="Auto", RichTextBox does not resize that way.

**Update:** Was able to get the RichTextBox to resize based on content/window resize by adding a FlowDocument tag with its "PageWidth" bound to the RichTextBox:

```
<RichTextBox Name="contentTextBox" Height="Auto" Width="Auto">
    <FlowDocument PageWidth="{Binding ElementName=contentTextBox, Path=ActualWidth}" />
</RichTextBox>
```